# Add a custom field to Woocommerce general setting in store address section

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, settings, custom-fields

I'm looking to add a Phone number field to the Woocommerce settings page. I can get the field to add to the settings list, but it gets appended to the bottom of the entire tab. Ideally I'd like to add the field in the **Store Address** sections on the general tab.

Here's what I'm using now (trimmed down):

```
add_filter('woocommerce_general_settings', 'woocommerce_add_phone');

function woocommerce_add_phone($settings) {

    $settings[] = array(
        'title'    => 'Phone Number',
        'type'     => 'text',
    );

    $sections[] = array( 'type' => 'sectionend', 'id' => 'store_address' );

    return $settings;

}
```

I made an attempt at using `array_splice` but couldn't get anywhere with it.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be done in a simple way targeting the **`woocommerce_store_postcode` field ID** to insert the Store phone custom field in this general settings at the right location:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_general_settings', 'general_settings_shop_phone');
function general_settings_shop_phone($settings) {
    $key = 0;

    foreach( $settings as $values ){
        $new_settings[$key] = $values;
        $key++;

        // Inserting array just after the post code in "Store Address" section
        if($values['id'] == 'woocommerce_store_postcode'){
            $new_settings[$key] = array(
                'title'    => __('Phone Number'),
                'desc'     => __('Optional phone number of your business office'),
                'id'       => 'woocommerce_store_phone', // <= The field ID (important)
                'default'  => '',
                'type'     => 'text',
                'desc_tip' => true, // or false
            );
            $key++;
        }
    }
    return $new_settings;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.

Tested and work… You will get something like:

[image]

Comment: This worked a treat! Thanks for the simple and thorough answer.

Answer (score 1):

LoicTheAztec code works fine but I wanted to find a solution without looping. Here is my version:

```
function add_phone_number_settings($settings) {
    // Search array for the id you want
    $key              = array_search('woocommerce_store_postcode', array_column($settings, 'id')) + 1;
    $custom_setting[] = array(
        'title'    => __('Phone Number'),
        'desc'     => __("Enter shop phone number"),
        'id'       => 'woocommerce_store_phone_number',
        'default'  => '',
        'type'     => 'text',
        'desc_tip' => true,
    );

    // Merge with existing settings at the specified index
    $new_settings = array_merge(array_slice($settings, 0, $key), $custom_setting, array_slice($settings, $key));
    return $new_settings;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_general_settings', 'add_phone_number_settings');
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will add your phone number after the post code element in the Store Address section.  I borrowed the splice function from [here](https://gist.github.com/jjgrainger/845271930a319079b74b).

```
add_filter('woocommerce_general_settings', 'woocommerce_general_settings_add_phone_number');

function woocommerce_general_settings_add_phone_number($settings) {

    $phone_number = array(
        'title'    => __( 'Phone Number', 'woocommerce' ),
        'desc'     => __( 'Add your phone number.', 'woocommerce' ),
        'id'       => 'woocommerce_store_phone_number',
        'default'  => '',
        'type'     => 'text',
        'desc_tip' => false,
    );

    $array_pos = 0;

    foreach ($settings as $key => $value) {
       if ( $value['id'] == 'woocommerce_store_postcode' ) {
            $array_pos = $key;
            break;
       }
    }

    $settings = array_insert( $settings, $phone_number, $array_pos + 1 );

    return $settings;
}

/*
    Array insert
    @array      the array to add an element to
    @element    the element to add to the array
    @position   the position in the array to add the element
 */
if(!function_exists('array_insert')) {
    function array_insert($array, $element, $position) {
        // if the array is empty just add the element to it
        if(empty($array)) {
            $array[] = $element;
        // if the position is a negative number
        } elseif(is_numeric($position) && $position < 0) {
            // if negative position after count
            if(count($array) + $position < 0) {
                $position = 0;
            } else {
                $position = count($array) + $position;
            }
            // try again with a positive position
            $array = array_insert($array, $element, $position);
        // if array position already set
        } elseif(isset($array[$position])) {
            // split array into two parts
            $split1 = array_slice($array, 0, $position, true);
            $split2 = array_slice($array, $position, null, true);
            // add new array element at between two parts
            $array = array_merge($split1, array($position => $element), $split2);
        // if position not set add to end of array
        } elseif(is_null($position)) {
            $array[] = $element;
        // if the position is not set
        } elseif(!isset($array[$position])) {
            $array[$position] = $element;
        }
        // clean up indexes
        $array = array_values($array);
        return $array;
    }
}
```